# Why does '/>' cause a text-coloring error in an html doc in gedit?

Tags: html, gedit, textcolor

```
$('#chatlog').append('<span class="'+colorCode+'">'+newMsg+'</span><br />');
```

See the `/>` at the end of the line? Those two characters turn greenish blue, and everything afterwards is just black-- it's like an error almost. No text coloring is present after that point in the document.

If I change it to `<br / >` (with a space between the `/` and the `>`) then it fixes the problem. But what's causing the problem in the first place?

Comment: Nevertheless, the doc is valid html. No errors occur in rendering.

Comment: Contact the author, report a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used Gedit, but older html specifications didn't allow for self-closing tags - you probably just need to tell it what flavor of html/xhtml/html5/whatever. A quick Google search says this is done by selecting the syntax highlighting language at the bottom right. :)